# Cant repaint in a loop

Tags: java, awt

I have a paintComponent method in a different class that extends JPanel:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    
    try {
        Draw.invoke(Main.newInstance(), g2);
    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException ex) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Paint!");
    
    g2.dispose();
}
```

And I'm attempting to repaint in a different class :

```
        while (running) {            
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            
            if (delta >= 1) {
                
                try {
                    Update.invoke(Main.newInstance());
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Delta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                
                gp.validate();
                gp.repaint();
                
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " Ticks: " + updates);
                avgUpdates = updates;
                updates = 0;
                avgFrames = frames;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
```

The update method does execute properly but the repaint method doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: I honestly hate the delta time loop, mainly because of how much CPU it uses. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: *super.paintComponents(g);* should be `super.paintComponent(g);` That code looks generally odd, and not legitimate. @GrindingForReputation is right, you should be using a Swing `Timer` and painting directly, not via some 'remote invocation'

Comment: 1. As g00se said, you need to call `super.paintComponent` (singular—no `s` in the method!). 2. Do not dispose of a Graphics object you did not create yourself. Never dispose of the Graphics passed to a Component’s painting method. 3. Most Swing methods are not legal to call from any thread other than the AWT event dispatch thread. Use a javax.swing.Timer (*not* java.util.Timer!) to repaint regularly. Or, use a [BufferStrategy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#createBufferStrategy(int,java.awt.BufferCapabilities)) to paint actively.